# Maven - how to set socks proxy via settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, proxy, socks

I wonder how I could set a SOCKS proxy for maven via the ~/.m2/settings.xml? Yes, I know there is a [recipe to do this via MAVEN_OPTS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy). But I would like to set this in the settings.xml within the <proxies> section. Which kind of protocol should I use? I already tried

- socks
- socks5
- SOCKS_5
- SOCKSv5

Regs,
  Gerd

Comment: Similar question, without answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267443/maven-to-use-socks-proxy-for-specific-repo

Comment: And also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129327/how-do-i-configure-maven-to-use-tor

Comment: And also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943317/maven-not-downloading-jars-behind-proxy

Answer (score 5):

This is my setting, and it worked fine for me,hope useful:

```
<proxy>
        <id>ss</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>socks5</protocol>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <host>127.0.0.1</host>
        <port>1080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I do not work in this environment any longer so I cannot test your solution.

Comment: What also worker for me is to run maven with: `-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=1080`